# Unity3d Probuilder scripting. How to apply texture in code?

Tags: api, unity-game-engine

I am creating primitive probuilder form in code:

```
m_mesh = ShapeGenerator.GenerateArch(
PivotLocation.FirstVertex,
angle: GetPrceduralParameters.Angle,
radius: GetPrceduralParameters.Radius,
width: GetPrceduralParameters.Thiknes,
depth: GetPrceduralParameters.Length,
radialCuts: GetPrceduralParameters.RadialCuts,
insideFaces: true,
outsideFaces: true,
frontFaces: true,
backFaces: true,
endCaps: true);
```

Then I want to put a material on it :

```
m_mesh.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial = m_elementMaterial;
```

And texture is tiled. The separate texture is on every face.

how to stratch the texture, or apply without tiling on every face?

Comment: I've exported generated model and checked it in Blender. The surfaces marked as strong (sharp). Need to unmark certain surfaces to make it look like after Blender smooth shading .

Answer (score 1):

The solution found:

```
 Smoothing.ApplySmoothingGroups(m_meshConcrete, m_meshConcrete.faces, 90);
 m_meshConcrete.Refresh();
```